# How to enforce greedy matching in Python regular expression

Tags: python-2.7

```
In [30]: s = '123 45$78 98@abc %'

In [31]: print re.findall(r'\b[\w]+ ?', s)
['123 ', '45', '78 ', '98', 'abc ']

In [32]: print re.findall(r'(\b[\w]+ ?)', s)
['123 ', '45', '78 ', '98', 'abc ']

In [33]: print re.findall(r'(\b[\w]+ ?)+', s)
['45', '98', 'abc ']
```

The expected results are as follows:

```
['123 45', '78 98', 'abc ']
```

Question> The focus of this question is not related to how to split a string. Instead, I want to know whether python allows us to do greedy matching.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python *does* greedy matching. The problem is that your regular expression seems to be wrong.

With `[\w]+ ?`, you are matching some characters, optionally *followed by* a space. What you seem to want is just some characters or spaces mixed together. Try this:

```
In [10]: re.findall(r'\b[\w ]+', s)
Out[10]: ['123 45', '78 98', 'abc ']
```